# What is an active region in sun's photosphere? Why sometimes there is an active region but no sunspots?

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun

What is the theory behind an active region?  If we check data in solar monitors,  there are some cases where there is no sunspot but there is still an active region.

Why is that the case?

Comment: Have your read the wiki article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot

Answer (score 0):

Active regions are observed in [EUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_ultraviolet) and [x-rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray) while [sunspots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot) are observed in white light.  Thus, sunspots tend to be identified as [photospheric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere) phenomena and active regions [coronal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona).  It can be the case that an active region is due to a sunspot, but it need not be.  See the link to the corona Wiki page and then look for the sub-header on Active Regions.

As an aside, the type of photons used to make an observation often correlate with altitude.  For instance, EUV and x-rays are typically found exclusively in the corona and white light down near the photosphere.  While both active regions and sunspots correspond to enhanced magnetic fields in spatially confined regions, they are seen at different altitudes.  Generally, a sunspot will have an active region overhead due to its enhanced magnetic fields, but an active region need not have a corresponding sunspot.

> What is the theory behind an active region?

The plasma in the photosphere, chromosphere, and corona are tied to the magnetic field, something called the [frozen-in condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics).  Bulk fluid-like motions can cause magnetic fields to accumulate in spatially confined regions.  If the fields get strong enough, they will actually reduce the thermal pressure of the plasma by pushing out the hotter particles, resulting in a sunspot if the region gets large enough.

Active regions can be the precursors to sunspots or never form into sunspots and just embody locally enhanced magnetic fields.  Sunspots are regions where the magnetic pressure dominates over the particle pressure, pushing out hotter particles.  The total pressure stays constant, i.e., the magnetic pressure plus the particle thermal pressure.

> Why is that the case?

Sunspots are an extreme, if you will.  They are the result of the magnetic forces dominating over the fluid forces.  Compared to active regions, they are rare.  Active regions are just regions of enhanced magnetic field identified as groups of loop structures seen in EUV and/or X-rays.  They form for the same reasons as sunspots but are just not as intense.

**Update**

> Why can there be active regions but no sunspot?

First, what is a sunspot?  A sunspot is identified as a (comparatively) dark region on the optical surface (photosphere) of the Sun.  They appear dark because they are effectively a pressure balance structure, where the magnetic pressure is balancing the thermal pressure.  Here, it is easier to cool the plasma than reduce the density (i.e., density gradients are more unstable than temperature gradients), so the thermal pressure can decrease in response to an increased magnetic pressure (the density is a little lower too, but mostly the temperature is lower).  If this is strong enough, a large, dark region will appear on the surface.

So one might ask, why do they occur in the first place?  First, look at my derivation and explanation for the *frozen-in* or *flux freezing* phenomena in [plasmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/452325/59023.  I reference that answer as the photosphere is a region where it applies well.  That is, if the bulk of the plasma moves, the magnetic field will follow (very crude explanation but bear with me).

So one way a sunspot can form is due to a magnetic flux tube (i.e., just think of a cylindrical region of plasma with much higher magnetic fields) that is more bouyant than the surrounding plasma.  They rise to the surface and can develop a pressure-balance relationship with the surrounding plasma.  As discussed above, their higher magnetic field strengths require a lower thermal pressure to remain in pressure balance and since it easier to lower the temperature (again crude language) the main drop in thermal pressure is due to a lower temperature than a lower density.  Since the brightness of a [black-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) source can be related to the temperature, the cooler region is seen as darker.

Finally, we return to the original question.  Why can there be active regions with no sunspots?  This is relatively simple as an active region is just a weaker form of a sunspot in many ways.  The Sun is controlled by magnetic fields and plasma/fluid dynamics.  Some regions are dominated by plasma/fluid dynamics, others by the magnetic fields.  The photosphere is the region where these two start to "fight" for dominance, if you will.  The [convection zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection_zone) is where the plasma/fluid dynamics dominate.

Active regions are regions of enhanced magnetic field but that does not mean there will necessarily be a large region of cooler plasma due to the enhanced magnetic fields.  The fields here are stronger than the surrounding plasma, but not upwards of 1000 times stronger like that in a sunspot.

Comment: i couldn't understand all of your point can you please, explain it completely?

Comment: Exactly. EUV and X-rays are from the Corona, not from active regions in the photosphere - which *are* observed in visible light, as plages.

Comment: @RobJeffries - Active regions are often identified as the arcades up in the corona, i.e., they are seen in EUV and x-ray data (e.g., from SDO).  They can often have an observable photospheric source like a sunspot, but they need not have a sunspot.

Comment: And the question is, why?

Comment: @RobJeffries - Ah yes, I see what you mean.  I will try to fix this later today or tomorrow...

Comment: @honeste_vivere: And what about sunspots which appear to have a very strong magnetic field, yet remain relatively warm? I'm looking at one in a complex region right now (AR 13576).

Comment: @OutisNemo - Not sure I follow.  I hope I did not imply that sunspots have to be X degrees cooler than the surrounding plasma or anything that quantitative, did I?  It's more of a general argument about pressure balance than a strict rule.

Comment: @honeste_vivere: I'm not trying to imply anything, I'm just asking how that fits in with what you wrote. At the time I wrote that the magnetic field strength as measured by HMI was very strong (and it wasn't a bug or artifact), but there was not much difference in the photospheric intensity. Also, if I'm not mistaken a sunspot is typically defined in terms of the photospheric intensity itself rather than the magnetic field strength, so the area I'm talking about would strangely enough not even have qualified as a sunspot, despite having a larger field strength than large spots surrounding it.

Comment: Active regions do have more intense magnetic fields than non-active regions.  At coronal altitudes, the temperature would be higher in these regions as well.  So far as I understand it, the pressure balance stuff that leads to the darkened region in the photosphere for a sunspot doesn't come about until some threshold magnetic field strength occurs, causing field lines to accumulate and pushing out hotter particles...

Comment: @honeste_vivere: I know ARs have more intense magnetic fields. I'm not new to Solar physics and Solar activity. The point here is that this particular region had a portion of it (I'm tempted to call it a spot, except for the fact that it only had the magnetic field and not the cooler temperature, hence the question) which had a very strong magnetic field, far beyond the threshold you typically see when it's associated with a spot as seen in terms of photospheric intensity (as measured and visualized on intensitygrams); and yet it was fairly cool, and in fact still remains that way even now.

Comment: @OutisNemo - Ask an independent question about this and clearly describe it and I will see if I can provide a better answer than I seem to be failing to do in this back-and-forth.